# wp-options table huge size very fast

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

i`m using wordpress last version with around 40 plugins.
the wp-options table become very large at around 1GB.
every day i reduced the size using wp-optimzer plugin.

[The most 15 value length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfVTU.jpg)
any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you narrow it down some more? What  is your what are the rows in wp-options that are increasing and which plugin is it associated with?

Comment: i add an image to my post , with the most 15 value length in wp-options table.